# is there a efficient way to use the field of related model in list_display?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

i have two models **user**(built-in django) model and a another model called **usertypes** which have **user** as a foreign key in it i made the **usertypes** model inline with **user** model. In **usertypes** model there is a field called staff_status, i wants to use this(staff_status) field in list_display. I have found a solution to this problem using callable but i also read that using callable func slows the process because it hits the database many times and then i read that using get_queryset can solve the problem, but i don't know how to use the query_set to solve this problem or is there another more efficient way to solve this problem.

```
class UserTypesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserTypes
    raw_id_fields = ['user']

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserTypesInline]
    list_display = ('username','staff',)

    def staff(self, instance):
      return instance.usertypes.staff_status

    # def get_queryset(self,request):
    #     qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    #     a = qs.select_related('usertypes')
    #     return a



admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

```
class UserTypes(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff_choices = (
        ('', ''),
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('Chef', 'Chef'),
        ('Delivery Boy', 'Delivery Boy'),
    )
    staff_status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=staff_choices, default=staff_choices[0][0]) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.staff_status
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`list_select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) attribute to tell Django to select the related items along with the original list queryset.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserTypesInline]
    list_display = ('username','staff',)
    list_select_related = ('usertypes',)

    def staff(self, instance):
      return instance.usertypes.staff_status
```

(I think your commented-out code would have worked, though - what happened when you tried it?)

Comment: the commented code shows this (<QuerySet [<User: cheff>, <User: sohail>, <User: superadmin>]> ) this only shows the name of the users but I want the staff_status which is in usertypes model

Comment: I remove both the functions get_queryset and def staff and use this code list_select_related = ('usertypes',)
list_display = ['username', 'usertypes']  is this way is correct or it does the same number of database hits as def staff function does?